# How to insert result of date difference into mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, date-difference

```
    <?php
    function find_days($start_date, $end_date) {
    $response = new stdClass();
    try {
    $sdate = new DateTime($start_date);
    $edate = new DateTime($end_date);
    $dateInterval = $edate->diff($sdate);
    $response->status = true;
    $response->result = $dateInterval;
    return $response;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    $response->status = false;
    $response->result = 'Invalid Date Format';
    return $response;
    }
    } 
    ?>            
    Start Date: <input type="date" name="sdate" placeholder="start date" /> 
    End Date: <input type="date" name="edate" placeholder="end date" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Find Days" />
    <?php
           if (isset($_POST['sdate']) && $_POST['sdate']) {
            $start_date = $_POST['sdate'];
            $end_date = $_POST['edate'];
            //now call the function
            $days_array = find_days($start_date, $end_date);
            if ($days_array->status) {
            echo " <input  type='text' name='day' 
            value='.$days_array>result>days.' />";
            $day = $_POST['day'];                   
            $query   = "INSERT into cart (date,edate,days) 
            VALUES('$start_date','$end_date','$day')";
            $success = $conn->query($query);
            if (!$success) {
            die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);  
            }
            } else {
                echo $days_array->result;
            }
        }
```

My code is working perfectly. But the result is displayed only on the screen.
So I've tried to store the result by placing it in a textbox and then insert into the table in a usual way. But I got an error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\date.php on line 45" 
I don't know how to rectify this.. please help me solve this.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: You need to express your dates as [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted strings, not as a PHP object which is arbitrarily interpolated: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to a string using [format](http://php.net/manual/de/dateinterval.format.php):

```
<?php
$now = new DateTime();
$hour = new DateTime( "now +1hours +13minutes +22seconds" );
$diff = $now->diff( $hour );

echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "\n";
echo $hour->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "\n";
echo $diff->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

**Output**

```
2018-07-26 20:53:42
2018-07-26 22:07:04
01:13:22
```